# How do I change security redirect behavior in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

If I make an AJAX request to a secured area, it sends a 302 header and then redirects to the login page in that request. Is there a way to configure the firewall to just give a different header and NOT redirect? Is that something I would need to handle in a `->before` call? Or would a better way be to override the authentication entry point, as suggested in [Symfony security return 401 response instead of redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662579/symfony-security-return-401-response-instead-of-redirect)? That is for Symfony so not sure if Silex has some better sugar.

Tried this and other things:

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'oauth' => array(
                'failure_path' => '/login',
                'with_csrf' => true
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/logout',
                'with_csrf' => true
            ),

        )
    ),

));

$app['security.authentication.entry_point.default.oauth'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new AuthenticationEntryPointComponent();
});

$app['security.authentication.entry_point.default.form'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new AuthenticationEntryPointComponent();
});
```

`default` is the name of the key in `security.firewalls`. Still getting the 302.

Comment: I would change the entry point authentication as you already suggested, because this is precisely the purpose of this class. Notice that a before call may not be enough to achieve what you want (at last while using the full security component, if you're rolling your own authorization system it's another issue)

Comment: Cool I'll give that a shot after holidays :) wanted to make sure I was heading right direction and not doing something crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig around so much code but got it:

My controller:

```
$app['security.entry_point.form._proto'] =$app->protect(function ($name, array $options) use ($app) {
  return $app->share(function () use ($app, $options) {
      $login_path = isset($options['login_path']) ? $options['login_path'] : '/login';
      return new MyCustomClass($app['security.http_utils'], $login_path);
  });
});
```

The class:

```
namespace Yours;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyCustomClass implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface {

  protected $_login_path = '/login';

  protected $_http_tools;

  /**
   * @param string $loginPath  The path to the login form
   */
  public function __construct(HttpUtils $http_utils, $login_path = '') {
    $this->_http_tools = $http_utils;

    if ( $login_path ) {
      $this->_login_path = $login_path;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) {
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
      $response = new Response(json_encode([]), 401);
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return $response;
    }

    return $this->_http_tools->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->_login_path);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem and was surprised that `SecurityServiceProvider` does not support `entry_point` option in firewal's configuration (just like Symfony security configuration does).

I've resolved it in different way. Instead of overriding `security.entry_point.form._proto` I followed `SecurityServiceProvider`built-in authentication factories and in my custom service provider's `register()` I wrote like this:

```
$app['security.authentication_listener.factory.MY_CUSTOM_FIREWALL'] = $app->protect(function ($name, array $options) use ($app) {
    $app['security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.anonymous'] = $app['security.authentication_provider.anonymous._proto']($name);
    $app['security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.anonymous'] = $app['security.authentication_listener.anonymous._proto']($name, $options);
    $app['security.entry_point.'.$name.'.MY_CUSTOM_FIREWALL'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
        return new MyCustomFirewallEntryPoint($app['url_generator']);
    });

    return [
        'security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.anonymous',
        'security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.anonymous',
        'security.entry_point.'.$name.'.MY_CUSTOM_FIREWALL',
        'anonymous'
    ];
});
```

and then in security config:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.firewalls' => [
        // All other routes require valid user
        'secured' => [
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'anonymous' => true,
            // It will search for custom factory
            'MY_CUSTOM_FIREWALL' => true
        ],
    ],
]);
```