# Unable to redirect to login page if user is not logged in

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function that gets executed when a web service is called. If the user is not logged in I want to redirect to login page. The front end I'm using is **AngularJS.**

The redirection is in the `else` part.

This is the function:

```
public function postCustomerGetAction(Request $request) {
$tokenValidationObj = new LoginController();
$isValid = $tokenValidationObj->postValidateUserTokenAction($request);

// print_r($this->customer_id);exit;
// print_r($this->association_id);

// print_r($isValid);exit;
if($isValid == 1){
    $log = new LogController();     
    $log->getLogJsonBody($this->get('logger'),$request);
    $display = new Result();
    try {
        $schema = 'customerGet.json';
        $validation = new InputValidation();
        $validationObj = $validation->dataValidation($request, $schema);
        $getKeyMap = array (
                "_customer_id"      => "customerId",
                "_customer_name"    => "customerName"
        );
        $getFunction = 'svk_apt_get_customer';
        $conObj = new ConnectionController();
        $conObj->beginTransaction();
        $dbres = $conObj->buildQuery($getFunction, $getKeyMap, $validationObj);
        $result = $display->getJsonResult($dbres);
        $conObj->dbCommitTransaction();
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        $log->getExceptionLog($this->get('logger'),$ex);
        $result = $display->getJsonException($ex);
    }
    return $result;
}else{
    $result = $this->container->getParameter('email_template_url');
    // print_r($result);exit;
    return new RedirectResponse($result);
    // header('Location: https://stackoverflow.com');exit;
    // return $this->redirect('https://stackoverflow.com');
}
```

}

In the response, I see the following html but it does not redirect to the page I am specifying. The html in response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://stackoverflow.com" />

            <title>Redirecting to https://stackoverflow.com</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Redirecting to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a>.
        </body>
    </html>
```

How do I redirect when the web service is called and user is not logged in?

Comment: The web service / API should not be redirecting the frontend to another page. If you are using Angular to interact with this web service, you should just return a "not logged in" status/flag, and then make Angular do the redirection.

Comment: @programmer-man i dont really know php. can i attach a property to the response object saying if user is logged in along with other properties like `RecordCount, Data` etc.

Comment: refer https://angular.io/guide/router for angular routing

Comment: @Leguy You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662579/symfony-security-return-401-response-instead-of-redirect

Comment: @programmer-man ok.. so is it ok if i send something like `isLoggedIn` in the header? i mean, is it the right way..

Comment: @Leguy HTTP Status 401 should be enough. Explanation: https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: @programmer-man ok thank you.. write as answer and i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web service / API should not be redirecting the frontend to another page. If you are using Angular to interact with this web service, you should just return a "not logged in" status/flag, and then make Angular do the redirection.

For a creating a custom response, you can refer to: [Symfony security return 401 response instead of redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662579/symfony-security-return-401-response-instead-of-redirect)

The HTTP Status 401 should be enough. More details about this status here: https://httpstatuses.com/401

Angular should detect that, and then redirect.